# Resource files (resx) does not respect Custom Tool Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces, manifest

In the resx properties, I changed the Custom Tool Namespace from `DefaultNamespace` to `MyNamespace.Language` and the following code is generated:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Language
{
  public class CommentResources
  {
    public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
      get {
           //removed code...
           global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("DefaultNamespace.CommentResources", typeof(CommentResources).Assembly);
  }
}
```

As you can see, only the class namespace is changed, but not the namespace passed in the ResourceManager constructor and because of that, when I instanciate `ResourceManager(typeof(CommentResources))` and try to access a key, it throws **MissingManifestResourceException**, for example:

```
var manager = new ResourceManager(typeof(CommentResources));
var resource = manager.GetString("myKey");
```

How can I truly changed the namespace?

**EDIT**:

Take a look at my solution below. Whenever I create a resx file within `Enviroment` folder, it creates a unwanted namespace. That's what's I'm trying to avoid

[image]

Comment: This one squarely fits your doctor's usual advice: "if it hurts then don't do it".  You'll have to explain why changing the namespace is important to you and why changing the project's default namespace setting is not good enough if you want an alternative approach.

Comment: This is not good enough. In one of my projects (csproj), I have to create one resx for each class, and there are several classes within folders, but those classes don't have the "folder" namespace and neither the resx should, so that's why. For example, there is a folder named `Enviroment` and I can't have that as part of namespace, because you know, `Enviroment` is already a class. That's just one example, there a several other folders just like that.

Comment: We have a very good money-back guarantee.  Please don't tell me, add it to your question.  Elaborate, especially the "folders" detail.

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled to the same issue.

It seems that Visual Studio 2017 generates code that creates [ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager) from **RootNamespace.SubFolder.ResourcesFileName** instead of **CustomToolNamespace.ResourcesFileName**.

Since the code is created from the Visual Studio's [Single-File Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/implementing-single-file-generators) tool called either ResXFileCodeGenerator (for internal class) or PublicResXFileCodeGenerator (for public class) that internally uses [StronglyTypedResourceBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.tools.stronglytypedresourcebuilder) class, there is no way to customize its behavior, other than implementing your own [Single-File Generator](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Single_File_Generator) as a Visual Studio extension and using it as a Generator for the EmbeddedResource.

Fortunately, there is a simpler workaround. In .csproj file, under EmbeddedResource tag, specify LogicalName tag with text value of **RootNamespace.SubFolder.ResourcesFileName.resources**.

In your specific case, it would look like this:

```
<LogicalName>DefaultNamespace.CommentResources.resources</LogicalName>
```

Comment: turns out I was wrong... `ResourceManager("DefaultNamespace.CommentResources", typeof(CommentResources).Assembly)` is right, this is not a bug. The first argument (`DefaultNamespace.CommentResources`) is the *path* of the embedded resx file within the assembly.